# Onmouseover on HTLML li tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onmouseover

I'm new to asp.net (and to stack overflow :) ) and I want a hint element to be shown on onmouseover event of li tags. I don't know how to set the position of the hint element. My code is something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function onmouseoveragent(e) {
        document.getElementById("agentVisit").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("agentVisit").offsetLeft = e.offsetLeft; /*e.????*/
        document.getElementById("agentVisit").offsetTop = e.offsetTop;   /*e.????*/
    };
</script>


<div class="node">
    <div class="taxonomy"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="contact-map">
            <ul>
                <li id="city1" onmouseover= "onmouseoveragent(this)">
                    <a "blabla">
                    <span class="hideme">city name</span>
                    </a>
                    <p class="hideme"> city name <strong class="tel">123456789</strong></p>
                </li>
                /*other list items*/ 
           </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="hr">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need a very good looking design to show your hint, you can use

```
<li title="city name">
```

---

update:

Check if it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/ysuw5/91/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I do need a good looking design which is given to me (that hideme class).